# WinForms: Respond to BindingSource being applied

Tags: c#, winforms, events, data-binding, binding

Is there an event that I can latch onto to be notified when the datasource has been applied to its bound controls?

Or is there another event, in which I am guaranteed that the data-source has been applied?

---

I'm working with WinForms (coming from WPF) and am using tags with data-bound values in order to determine the type of control I'm working with.  Many controls could have the same tag value, and I must retrieve the controls with the desired tag in order to perform business logic.

The problem is that I do not know when to perform my search for the tag values.  I've attempted to search for the tag values immediately after calling:

```
myBindingSource.DataSource = OutputFunctions.Instance;
//Yes... I'm binding to a singleton with a list of properties.
//Its not the best method, but works.
```

inside my `Form.Load` event handler.  But, during the search, I've seen that the tag values are not set.  How can this be if I've just set the data source?

As can be seen from the internally managed code-behind for my form, I have properly set the value through the designer's Property window:

```
this.textBoxDTemp.DataBindings.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Binding(
    "Tag",
    this.myBindingSource,
    "KNOB_DRIVER_TEMP",
    true));
```

I've taken a look at the `BindingComplete`, which honestly looks very promising, except that it doesn't trigger during the initialization of the binding, even though the value supposedly is propagating from the data-source to the target control.

**EDIT:**
Per requested, the data-source is first set in the internal code-behind for the form as such:

```
this.myBindingSource.DataSource = typeof(OutputFunctions);
```

And here is the singleton in case it helps.

```
public class OutputFunctions
{
    private static OutputFunctions instance;

    public static OutputFunctions Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (instance == null)
            {
                instance = new OutputFunctions();
            }
            return instance;
        }
    }

    private OutputFunctions() { }

    public string KNOB_DRIVER_TEMP { get { return "KNOB_DRIVER_TEMP"; } }
    public string KNOB_PASSENGER_TEMP { get { return "KNOB_PASSENGER_TEMP"; } }
    public string KNOB_FAN { get { return "KNOB_FAN"; } }
}
```

Comment: What does `myBindingSource.DataSource` property contain before setting it? I can't duplicate the case. If I leave DataSource blank, then I get an exception before load event. If I set it to something like `typeof(MyDataObject)`, then the load event fires and after setting it to the actual instance, tags are updated immediately. Are you sure you set data source inside the load event or in constructor?

Comment: You might be trying to solve the wrong problem. You can do MVVM in WinForms- keep the viewmodel independent of the view and bind it to the controls using binding sources and custom binding code. (View model logic should *never* interact with controls and their tags. The view model should represent the state using objects. Interacting with controls and tags is the job of the binding source, event handlers and occasionally custom view-specific binding code to bind to those objects and represent their state.)

Comment: @IvanStoev Strange.  The code-behind sets it to the `typeof(OutputFunctions)` which should initialize an empty BindingList if I understand right.  After I set the singleton instance, I search for the tags but cannot find them.

Comment: @jnm2 I most certainly am solving the wrong problem! :)  I'm working with an old project and upgrading it in pieces.  To be honest, I want to scrap the old project and write anew in WPF using MVVM.

Comment: @NickMiller Ok, so its the second case. Actually setting `BindingSource.DataSource` to a `Type` (instead of an instance) allows the framework to find the properties and bind correctly. So at form load time, the binding already happened, so setting the data source should apply immediately. Are your controls reside in some `ContainerControl`?

Comment: @IvanStoev If you have a working example, feel free to post an answer.  I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: @NickMiller I will, but I'm trying to duplicate your case, and I can't. The only thing I know so far is that the binding does not work for controls with Visible = false, if that helps

Comment: @IvanStoev, Yes! I discovered that just this moment!  My controls are initially invisible.  How can I work with that? Ideally I'd like to do this before the controls are visible, as a fallback I could after the controls are visible.

Comment: @NickMiller Yeah, that's one of the WF flaws (or features?). I've posted a workaround.

Comment: @NickMiller I've been enjoying MVVM in WinForms for a while now, so it *is* possible to keep it clean. I write the view model as though it was going to be used in WPF, except that I use parameterless methods instead of ICommands. Then I bind everything to UI using the BindingSource and event handlers to call the view model's action methods. Sometimes after you have a working, testable view model you need to write extra view code to bind the view to the view model but the important thing is that no business logic knows about the view.

Comment: @NickMiller the thing with visibility is that you can leave the control initially visible as long as you assign the viewmodel to the binding source in the form's constructor. The user will never see the button because binding sets the visibility to false before the thread does any painting. This way you don't need the CreateControl workaround.

Comment: @NickMiller if you want to go all the way, use Castle Windsor or your IoC container of choice, inject every view model with a custom navigation service. When you need to show another form, the view model tells the navigation service to load another view model, the service creates and shows the view that goes with the view model by convention (I use type name- FooBarView is the form that binds to FooBarViewModel) and then your view models are 100% view agnostic. It's bliss.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Data binding should already been activated before your form load event. The problem you are experiencing is because due to to data binding infrastructure optimization, binding does not happen for invisible controls until they become visible for a first time. This is probably because the designers of WF were thinking that the data binding will be used to bind data properties only (like `Text` etc.) and doesn't make sense to do that for an invisible controls.

If you are not afraid to use some internals (or as user HighCore would say hacks), then the following helper would help solving your problem (we are using something similar for a years):

```
public static class ControlUtils
{
    static readonly Action<Control, bool> CreateControlFunc = (Action<Control, bool>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action<Control, bool>),
        typeof(Control).GetMethod("CreateControl", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic, null, new[] { typeof(bool) }, null));
    public static void CreateControls(this Control target)
    {
        if (!target.Created)
            CreateControlFunc(target, true);
        else
            for (int i = 0; i < target.Controls.Count; i++)
                target.Controls[i].CreateControls();
    }
}
```

and just put at the beginning of your form load event handler

```
this.CreateControls();
```

Comment: Brilliant.  I had no idea you could take advantage of internals like that.  Although HighCore has a fair point in calling them hacks because you have completely violated the intended scope of that function.  Apparently the visibility behavior is documented (see [Control.CreateControl Method ()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.createcontrol(v=vs.110).aspx)).  Thanks much!

Comment: @NickMiller You welcome. But I would rather ask MS why I'm supposed to use hacks - the function exists, so it has use cases, so why make it internal. Take care.

Comment: I ran into this. This workaround isn't necessary if the control is set as initially visible in the designer because binding will take care of making it invisible. As long as the binding source's data source is set during the constructor, the binding happens immediately before the thread draws anything, so the user never sees the control.

Comment: @jnm Correct, but see the comments in the thread. OP case is exactly the one that needs a workaround. Also note that if you are using tab control in your form, all the controls contained inside the inactive pages will not bind regardless of whether they've been set to Visible in design time or not. This method ensures all the controls are created (the second parameter of the internal method is called `ignoreVisible` and the public `CreateControl` just passes `false`).

Comment: @IvanStoev What I'm saying is that there is no such case. OP does not need to have the control set invisible in the designer. The same visual result can be obtained by leaving it visible and relying on binding to hide it.

Comment: @jnm2, I think you are correct that you can use bindings to hide the controls. The bindings still trigger because controls are initially visible from the designer. Despite this, I'm not relying on the complete power of data-binding (as I should be), and the workaround mentioned by Ivan Stoev addresses my particular setup. In regards to tab controls, it seems that bindings will not trigger until a tab becomes visible. Only one tab can be visible at design time, so bindings only trigger for the first tab. This hack would allow data-binding to happen for all tabs at startup.  Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for the control's

"BindingContextChanged" event.

Are you trying to force add some hook to the binding when it occurs?.

Since you are looking AFTER the entire form is prepared and bindings are established, you can probably hook to the "LOAD" event.  The form prepares everything first, then will call the "Load" event.  If anything is subscribed (listening) to it, they will be notified.  Once that is invoked, you can run and cycle through all controls on the form and look for whatever part / component / tag / control type, etc.

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.VisibleChanged += Form1_VisibleChanged;
    }

    void Form1_VisibleChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!this.Visible)
            return;

        // Disable the event hook, we only need it once.
        this.VisibleChanged -= Form1_VisibleChanged;

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
            sb.AppendLine(c.Name);
    }
```

Edit per comment.  I changed from the LOAD event to the VISIBILITY event.  At this point, the form is now being shown so all your stuff SHOULD be completed and available.  So, the initial check is to make sure it IS becoming visible.  If so, immediately remove itself from the event handler, you only need it done once and not every possible time it gets shown / hidden / shown ...

Comment: This looks helpful.  It appears that if the binding context changes for one control, then the bound tags should be available all at once.  How to you properly set/change the binding context of the top-level form?

Comment: @NickMiller, revised answer... does this help you.

Comment: Yes, this does help.  It is actually what I'm currently doing, but I am finding out that the control doesn't have the bound tag value because the controls are invisible at the time the `Form.Load` handler is called.

Comment: @NickMiller, see revision working with VISIBILITY being changed.