# Searching DataGridViews contained in multiple tab pages

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, tabs

I have one or two datagridviews in seven different tabs. I have a search box that worked fine when just searching the datagridview in the current selected tab, however searching across multiple tabs has proved to be a problem. The first time the search is used, nothing happens. After that, when the substring that's being searched for is found, the correct tab is shown, however the row containing the substring is not highlighted. If I search again without changing tab pages, the correct row will be highlighted... Thank you in advance for the help! Here are my methods:

```
 private void searchBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        // Declare DGV
        DataGridView DGV = null;
        bool isFound = false;
        int tabIndex = -1;

        // When a key is pressed and it's the enter key...
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            // Loop through all tab pages
            for (int i = 0; i < tabs.TabCount; i++)
            {
                // Loop through all controls in the selected tab
                foreach (Control c in tabs.TabPages[i].Controls)
                {
                    // if the control is a datagridview, cast it as a datagridview, 
                    // and set DGV equal to it
                    if (c is DataGridView)
                    {
                        DGV = (DataGridView)c;
                        string name = DGV.Name;

                        // Pass in DGV to Search() to search all cells within it for 
                        // the term in the searchbox
                        isFound = Search(DGV);
                    }

                    if (isFound)
                        tabIndex = i;
                }
            }

            if (tabIndex >= 0)
            {
                tabs.SelectTab(tabIndex);
                tabs.SelectedTab.Show();
                highLightSearchRows();
            }
        }
    }
```

This is my Search method:

```
private bool Search(DataGridView dataGrid)
    {
        int i, j;
        bool retval = false;

        // Makes sure searchBox contains text before searching
        if (searchBox.TextLength <= 0)
            return false;

        string searchBoxText = searchBox.Text, sub1 = searchBox.Text.Substring(1);

        // Doesn't accept an empty string as a valid search parameter
        if (searchBoxText == "")
            return false;

        string searchForText = searchBoxText;

        // Starts looping from the bottom of the grid up
        // This makes FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex show the uppermost match in the grid
        for (i = dataGrid.Rows.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            // If any cells contain the search string, they are highlighted
            if (dataGrid.Rows[i].Cells.OfType<DataGridViewCell>()
                .Any(cell => ((dynamic)cell.Value).Contains(searchForText)))
                retval = true;

            // Deselect all rows in all datagrids in order for other rows to                
            // be programmatically selected
            dataGrid.Rows[i].Selected = false;
        }

        return retval;
    }
```

And the highlight rows method:

```
private void highLightSearchRows()
    {
        DataGridView DGV = null;
        int rowIndex = -2;

        foreach (Control c in tabs.SelectedTab.Controls)
        {
            // if the control is a datagridview, cast it as a datagridview,
            // and set DGV equal to it
            if (c is DataGridView)
            {
                DGV = (DataGridView)c;
                string name = DGV.Name;

                foreach (DataGridViewRow row in DGV.Rows)
                {
                    // If any cells contain the search string, they are highlighted
                    if (row.Cells.OfType<DataGridViewCell>()
                        .Any(cell => ((dynamic)cell.Value).Contains(searchBox.Text)))
                    {
                        // Makes selected row the top row in the view
                        rowIndex = row.Index;
                        row.Selected = true;
                        DGV.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = rowIndex;
                    }

                    if (rowIndex >= 0)
                    {
                        // Select the matching row
                        row.Selected = true;
                        rowIndex = -2;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried to **Debug** what's going on?

Comment: Can you post the `DataGridView` settings? I know there is multiple, but I would assume most are the same?

Comment: @Ivan Stoev Yes, the substrings are found, and the tab page the string is on is displayed, however the row doesn't highlight unless the tab page it's in is selected.

Comment: @KDecker I'm using Visual Studio 2013, is there a way to copy them all at once? I wasn't able to find anything online

Comment: After a quick look at your code, I found a not-so-good point which you are repeating systematically: not exiting the loop after finding what you looking for (a mere `break` inside the corresponding conditions should be enough). This provokes your code to be unnecessarily unefficient and, what is worse, to potentially trigger errors. In fact, it seems that what you complaining about (rows not being highlighted) is precisely provoked by not having exited the loop on time: in `highLightSearchRows()`, after finding row, none of the loops are exited (the ones through tabs/controls in tab)...

Comment: Many things in WinForms work differently before the control is made visible (really) for the first time. You may try forcing the control creation (including the ones inside the inactive tab pages) during the form load with the helper method from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33307160/winforms-respond-to-bindingsource-being-applied/33309549#33309549)

Comment: ... what explains the irregular behaviour you are complaining about: even in case of highlighting the right row, it might be the case that further tabs/datagridviews are found and, consequently, the loop would analyse them afterwards (by eventually updating the previous selection). Additionally, you should improve other bits of your code (also potentially prone to errors) like the fact of going through all the tabs/controls twice (why not getting all the required information the first time?!).

Comment: @IvanStoev Firstly, the problem of the OP is provoked by his wrong algorithm (as highlighted in my comments). Secondly, you shouldn't deliver generic statements mainly when being very misleading like "Many things in WinForms work differently before the control is made visible (really) for the first time" (I guess that you meant waiting for the form load event) what is wrong. This kind of questions/errors are usually provoked by faulty codes, if you don't feel like analysing the code in the given moment, it might be better if you plainly let it go :)

Comment: @varocarbas I'm not arguing against the points in your comment - in fact I agree with all of them. But I stay on my point based on my long time WinForms experiense. I'm not saying the problem here is the same (that's why I'm suggesting OP to try), but at least data binding doesn't work normally before the control is created, which happens on first `OnVisibleChanged`

Comment: You could try calling Refresh on the control before highlighting it. [https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.refresh%28v=vs.110%29.aspx]

Comment: @IvanStoev I got your point (I reflected it in the last update of my comment). I also always recommend to not do anything before form load; but your previous comment seemed too confusing to me ("control made visible"...). In any case, I took advantage of the opportunity to write a small piece of advice (you are kind of new here).

Comment: @varocarbas I always read your comments with pleasure. And really  appreciate any advice by you, thanks!

Comment: @IvanStoev I utilized your helper method but with no success. I really do think the problem has something to do with the invisibility factor.

Comment: @varocarbas I initially didn't break from the loop because I wanted all rows that contained the string to be highlighted. I did implement the breaks in the loops, but nothing has changed. Would you like me to update my code now?

Comment: @SteveWellens I tried this but it didn't work. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: @David Can you prepare a small complete example code that we can run and see the problem. It doesn't need to be a real. Also I'm wondering how do you populate your grids - unbound or bound, if bound, what type of data source etc.

Comment: @IvanStoev I'll quick make one

Comment: @David Your code is not precisely perfect, but simple enough to know what it can do. If you put breaks in all your loops (bear in mind that if you have 2 nested loops you would have to set some kind of flag to let the most external one know when to exit) and perform the tabs/datagridviews analysis just once, I am sure that you will get what you want (at least, a consistent/always-same behaviour). Bear in mind that SO is not meant for helping you learn debugging or giving step-by-step guidance, this question is completely off-topic and you have got already enough info to solve it by your own.

Comment: @IvanStoev Thanks for the nice words. You are free to continue chatting with the OP, I personally will stop contributing here. It is clear that you want to help and your attitude is really good; that's why my previous advice and the following one (to maximise so much energy :)): testing all the possible scenarios is a quite good proceeding, although is better to narrow down the problem and to test only what is likely to provoke it. For example: an irregular behaviour (working/not working; much more when dealing with row highlighting) is very unlikely to have anything to do with bindings.

Comment: @IvanStoev I made a small code and it worked... I'll keep looking at it. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @varocarbas Thank you for your help!

Comment: Those comments ar terribly long. Just my 2cts: Tabpages that don't show do not refresh their content. So __first__ select the page and __then__ select the row!