# Bindingsource not updating bound controls in separate panel

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, bindingsource

I have a form with 2 panels on top of each other. The second panel is initially invisible and behind the first panel. These panels contain controls that are all bound to a binding source.

The first time the form is loaded and a record is loaded from the database, the binding source is not setting the values of the controls on the second panel. It is when I bring this panel to the front that the values are set.

Is this default behavior? Is there a way to force bound controls to have values set to them even if they are still hidden?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33307160/winforms-respond-to-bindingsource-being-applied/33309549#33309549 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34907430/winform-tabcontrol-tab-page-contents-does-not-update-until-the-new-tab-is-shown/34910027#34910027

Comment: @IvanStoev Works like a charm!! wow!!