# How to verify control's databinding match the bindingsource?

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, bindingsource

I have complex forms where controls are on various tabs and panels. These forms use a bindingsource to bind their controls to the data source.

There might be situations during development where the data source's members have been renamed but not the forms' controls.

As no exception is thrown on loading the form, is there a way to loop through the bindingsource's datasource members and compare them with the controls' databinding values?

Particular attention must be made to hidden controls, as explained in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33307160/winforms-respond-to-bindingsource-being-applied/33309549#33309549).

Where should this check take place? In the constructor or `OnLoad`? (It should at least happen after `InitializeComponent` because the bindingsource's datasource, ie. typeof(myObject) is set in this method).

Comment: When data-binding to properties of acontrol, if the property doesn't exist in datasource, an exception will raise: `Cannot bind to the property or column XXXXXX on the DataSource.`

Comment: @RezaAghaei No Exception is being raised.

Comment: Exception is raised, but not thrown  - check your Exception settings. Then in some cases if exception thrown in `Load` eventhandler it will be swallow - in that cases you can wrap `Load` event handler with `Try.. catch`

Comment: @Fabio What's the exception that should be thrown?

Comment: You can see the exception in the first comment. It's `ArgumentException`.

Comment: And maybe you can use feature of new compiler `nameof` instead of hard coding names of properties [nameof (C# and Visual Basic Reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986596.aspx)

Comment: @Fabio Woot was happy to read your advice, until I realize I was still using Visual Studio 2010 :-(

Answer (score 0):

The binding object has the event bindingcomplete which could help you to get the statut (sucess-error) of a binding operation (read-write).

Don't forget to enable the formatting on the databinding. Without that the event is not raise.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k26k86tb(v=vs.100).aspx

As the purpose of Databinding is to "link" business object property to graphical control property, the hidden control won't "read" the value until the control become visible. You should access directly the business databoundobject, instead of the reading the property of a UI control.

Wrapping your Load with a Try Catch is also a good thing (in every case), because exception thrown in this event are silently catched by Winforms. This could make the form to be loaded and visible with only half of your "loading process code".

Comment: You can simply test data-binding to an invalid property: `this.DataBindings.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("Text", this, "XXXXXX", true));` An exception will raise: *System.ArgumentException: Cannot bind to the property or column XXXXXX on the DataSource.
Parameter name: dataMember*

Comment: What about if you create the binding before the IList dataobject is initialized (with the designer by exemple ?) or if the type of the source is changed after. If I have good memory no exception are thrown in this case.

Comment: I've set `ArgumentException` to be thrown. I've also added `try...catch` in the form's construtor and `OnLoad` methods. The exception is still not thrown.

Comment: It doesn't make any difference. It's simple to test, for example  `var bs = new BindingSource(); bs.DataSource= typeof(Form); this.DataBindings.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("Text", bs, "XXXXXX", true));` As you can see in the example, we didn't pass an instance of the expected object (here `Form`) to binding source.

Comment: @RezaAghaei I've added your test in the form's constructor without a `try...catch`. No exception is thrown!!

Comment: @RezaAghaei And if you change the type of the datasource after creating the binding ?

Comment: @MarcoGuignard It also doesn't make any difference. For example see this code: `var bs = new BindingSource();
bs.DataSource = typeof(Form); 
this.DataBindings.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("Text", bs, "TopMost", true));
bs.DataSource = this;
bs.DataSource = new Button();` It also throws an exception on last statement.

Comment: @MarcoGuignard The OP need to post [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to reproduce the problem. Also the idea is somehow odd. Maybe it's an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Currently the question has nothing useful for the OP or future readers.